# Lexical Gap translation help!

Tags: translation, word-requests, english-to-japanese, terminology

I'm writing a speech in Japanese about the difference between languages and I've been trying to figure out the correct way to say "lexical gap" in Japanese. Any ideas?

Comment: We usually ask people to show some research effort for translation questions, but in this case I think there's no easy answer to look up, so I think we can keep this question open as it is :-)

Answer (score 3):

It would usually be 「語彙的欠落{ごいてきけつらく}」、「語彙の欠落」、「語彙欠落」, etc.

In linguistics within the Japanese-speakng world, however, many technical terms are often written both in English and Japanese.  This is true of the ***newer*** fields of study such as linguistics, computer science, psychology, etc.

Thus, I might suggest that you consider wording such as 「語彙的欠落  (lexical gap)」, 「語彙的欠落  (英語では"lexical gap")」」, etc.